# Any way to easily persist Entity Framework's ChangeTracker into a schema, perhaps using Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, savechanges, changeset, audit-trail

I commonly need to implement auditing in my EF projects and have found that the built-in `ChangeTracker` to be the most effective way to determine, well, the changes that have been made. In the past, I've made attempts of varying complexity to persist `ChangeTracker` via my own object model, usually with a `ChangeSet` representing a successful `SaveChanges` result, a `ChangeSetItem` being a particular entity-property/relation-value-action combination, and so forth.

Does everyone do something like this to deal with auditing? Do they create audit tables on a purely ad-hoc, per-audited-entity basis? Or (what I am hoping for) is there some obvious way that I might be able to persist the `ChangeTracker` members themselves, perhaps using Code First, to cut out the middle man and the mistakes he (I) make?